# How to remove unexpected hover value in Plotly Express bar plot, Python

Tags: python, plotly, hover

I am using plotly express for creating a horizontal bar plot. After adding `hovertamplate`, an ugly zero appeared in hover box (always a zero for each element). What is it and how can I get rid of it?
Thanks.

```
fig = px.bar(df, orientation = 'h')

fig.update_traces(hovertemplate = "%{label}, in %{value} drugs")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Solution found here](https://community.plotly.com/t/tooltip-in-dash-shows-trace-0-how-to-get-rid-of-that/36844/2) if any one needs it, too:

"...need to add `<extra></extra>` at the end of the `hovertemplate`, as [here](https://plotly.com/python/hover-text-and-formatting/#customize-tooltip-text-with-a-hovertemplate). The `<extra>` tag is for the second part of the hover, in a different color, where usually the trace name is displayed."